# Parsing nested JSON fields in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am pretty new to Snowflake and I am now trying to parse a JSON field and pull its attributes to return in the response.

I tried a few variations but every time, the attribute is populating as `null`.

`attributes` **column in my table has this JSON**:

```
{
    "Status": [
        "ACTIVE"
    ],
    "Coverence": [
        {
            "Sub": [
                {
                    "EndDate": [
                        "2020-06-22"
                    ],
                    "Source": [
                        "Test"
                    ],
                    "Id": [
                        "CovId1"
                    ],
                    "Type": [
                        "CovType1"
                    ],
                    "StartDate": [
                        "2019-06-22"
                    ],
                    "Status": [
                        "ACTIVE"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I tried**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    from
        (
            TRIM(mt."attributes":Status, '[""]')::string as STATUS,
            TRIM(r.value:"Sub"."Id", '[""]')::string as ID,
            TRIM(r.value:"Sub"."Source", '[""]')::string as SOURCE
            from "myTable" mt,
            lateral flatten ( input => mt."attributes":"Coverence", outer => true) r
        )
    GROUP BY
        STATUS,
        ID,
        SOURCE;
```

**Later I tried**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    from
        (
            TRIM(mt."attributes":Status, '[""]')::string as STATUS,
            TRIM(r.value:"Id", '[""]')::string as ID,
            TRIM(r.value:"Source", '[""]')::string as SOURCE
            from "myTable" mt,
            lateral flatten ( input => mt."attributes":"Coverence":"Sub", outer => true) r
        )
    GROUP BY
        STATUS,
        ID,
        SOURCE;
```

But nothing worked. The `STATUS` is populating as expected. But `ID` and `SOURCE` are populating `null`.

Am I missing something or have I done something dumb? Please shed some light.

Comment: Do you have any ability to change the source JSON? Things that according to their names should be simple properties are stored as arrays. For example, EndDate, Source, Id, Type, StartDate, and Status are all stored as arrays. Some could conceivably have more than one value, but why would a StartDate be an array? Perhaps this could be converted to using scalar values instead of arrays. There is a way to process this using JSON techniques, but it would be simpler/cleaner if the source could be modified. This may not be possible though.

Comment: Yes Greg. But the catch is, all the attributes you mentioned can have multiple values. For the example I provided, it holds only one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Coverence` could contain multiple `Sub`, therefore FLATTEN twice. At lowest level only first element is chosen (`EndDate[0]`, `Source[0]` etc):

```
SELECT 
   mt."attributes":Status[0]::TEXT AS Status
  ,r2.value:EndDate[0]::TEXT AS EndDate
  ,r2.value:Source[0]::TEXT AS Source
  ,r2.value:Id[0]::TEXT AS Id
FROM myTable AS mt,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => mt."attributes",
                path => 'Coverence',
                outer => true) r1,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => r1.value,
                path => 'Sub',
                outer => true) r2;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All your elements are array type and the overall JSON is not making much sense... so to access all your individual elements, you have to use [] notation and then you can access the element values. You don't need to use flatten also, if you just have to access individual elements via index.

Comment: Yes Roy. This JSON is something which we get from an external API. We don't have much control over it. I will try your solution for sure. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for anyone who comes across this in the future, wouldn't really know how to accomplish this SQL-wise, but seeing its JSON from an external API I have used this tool called GetOurData. I know they do have pre-built connectors for api's but If you contact their Dev team (what I had to do) they'll make you a custom connection for your API. I think they're still in beta so it should be free as well.

Comment: Heya and welcome to SO. This answer is more a recommendation than an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the schema in advance it should be quite easy but cumbersome. You need to basically flatten all arrays to the lowest level as in (not complete):

```sql
select status.value as status, end_date.value as end_date from json, 
lateral flatten(json_field:Status) as status,
lateral flatten(json_field:Coverence) as coverence,
lateral flatten(coverence.value:Sub) as sub,
lateral flatten(sub.value:EndDate) as end_date
```

where `json` is simply `select parse_json(<your json content>) as json_field`.

If you would like to try a more dynamic schema inference you can try using `recursive => true` attribute for `flatten` function (ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten).